# how to also export linked files in emacs org mode automatically?

Tags: org-export

If i have `[[file:./test.org][test]]` inside of example.org.

How can i achieve that i automatically export test.org to test.html, when i Export my Example.org to HTML?

Is there a Option i can enable to achieve this behavior?

I didn't find anything underneath [Export-settings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Publishing** multiple html files in org: https://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing.html#Publishing

If we assume that your org files reside in ~/tmp, then you can export them in one go with <kbd>C-c C-e P p</kbd> after evaluating below definition

```
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(
    ("org-files"
     :base-directory "~/tmp"
     :base-extension "org"
     :publishing-directory "~/tmp/html"
     :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
     )
    ("example" :components ("org-files"))
    )
      )
```

They will be exported to the directory ~/tmp/html.

Alternatively - maybe rethinking your approach - you could **importing** the content of "test.org" directly into your "example.org" html export with an `#+include` directive: https://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html.

```
#+INCLUDE: "test.org"
```